# Best strategy to load custom UIView with XIB and Outlets

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

What is best strategy to load custom `UIView`s with XIB and Outlets? At this moment I have code listed below. I think this code is bad because I have 2 UIViews as container and in future probably problem with constraints.

- `UIViewController` ( I don't want all outlets and actions in one big ViewController  )

  ```
  func showCategories() {
       if(self.categoriesView == nil) {
           self.categoriesView = CategoriesView()
       }

       self.view.addSubview(self.categoriesView!)
  }
  ```
- Custom UIView - CategoriesView

  ```
  class CategoriesView, ...protocols... {

  @IBOutlet var table:UITableView!

  override init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override init(frame:CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
  }

  override init() {
      super.init()

      let views   = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CategoriesView", owner: self, options: nil)
      let view    = views![0] as CategoriesView
      self.frame  = view.frame

      self.addSubview(view)
  }

  ....

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apple's MVC, it's best to avoid views with too much logic in them. If you want to compose a complex view using component subviews, then look at [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

If you are already using storyboards, a container view will take care of most of the complexity for your.